# What is the meaning and proof of Harvey Friedman’s ultrafinite incompleteness sentence?

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, reverse-math, theories-of-arithmetic, ultrafinitism

On page 7 of his [paper](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/AdvIncomp03011712pt-1k0z6to.pdf) “Adventures in Incompleteness”, Harvey Friedman states the following:

> IN ANY LONG ENOUGH SEQUENCE $x_1,...,x_n$ FROM $\{1,2,3\}$, SOME $(x_i,...,x_{2i})$ IS A SUBSEQUENCE OF SOME LONGER $(x_j,...,x_{2j})$.
> ...
>
> - Size for [this] is > 7198th Ackermann function at 158,386 = $A_{7198}(158,386)$.
> - Any proof of [this] in EFA = exp function arithmetic, needs $> A_{7198}(158,385)$ symbols, a bit much. Same for SEFA.
> - This is an ULTRA FINITE INCOMPLETENESS.

He calls it ultrafinite incompleteness because an ultrafinitist would presumably not accept a statement requiring such a long proof.  In any case, what is the definition of nth Ackerman function Friedman is relying on? And what is the proof that this statement is true, and moreover that this statement is provable in $EFA$ but only with such an absurdly long proof?

I assume there’s a much shorter proof in some stronger system, as presumably Friedman did not write down a proof with $> A_{7198}(158,385)$ symbols!

Comment: Harvey Friedman, Long finite sequences,  J. Combin. Theory Ser. A, 95 (1) (2001), 102–144. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316500931546

Comment: Re: provability of provability in EFA without actually proving in $\mathsf{EFA}$, note that $\mathsf{WKL_0}$ proves that the statement in question is equivalent to the finiteness of a particular "nicely definable" (e.g. $\Delta_1$) subtree of $3^{<\omega}$; the right-to-left direction of this equivalence is outright $\mathsf{EFA}$-provable. By $\Sigma_1$-completeness of $\mathsf{EFA}$, provable in $\mathsf{WKL_0}$, we get a $\mathsf{WKL_0}$-proof that if Friedman's sentence is true then it is provable in $\mathsf{EFA}$.

Comment: In particular, letting [F] be the sentence in question, it is *not* claimed that $\mathsf{EFA}$ *itself* can prove "$\mathsf{EFA}$ proves [F]" in any reasonable amount of symbols.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can WKL_0 prove (in a small number of lines) that [F] is true though?  If not, how strong a system do you need to prove [F]?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan No idea. I suspect not. My point was just that there's a general technique to these "some-long-proof" ideas.